# SQL Trigger with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Why does this code throw an error?

```
using (ProviderContext db = new ProviderContext())
{
  string sqlcommand = @"GO CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger] ON [dbo].[News] FOR    insert AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT OFF insert [Statistics](NewsStatID) select NewsID from inserted update [Statistics] set Hits = '0' update [Statistics] set Positive = '0' update [Statistics] set Negative = '0' END";
  db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlcommand);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Because your syntax is wrong?

GO is not a keyword SQL Server understands - it is a feature of the management studio.

To quote from the documentation (obvious that is in there, is it not?):

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.

Now, you are not in the utilities, so the key word is not recognized. It also makes no sense. As in: it is not needed.

And btw., that is also wrong:

> set Negative = '0'

Youc an just write

> set Negative = 0

SQL Server is totally capable of dealing with numbers.